# Currency Symbol doesnt change

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

I have setup 3 magento websites, one for EN, AU and US. I did it as seperate websites as I want to change the price to a fixed price for each currency.

I have setup the three different currencies and change the price for each store against each product.

The price does change depending on the store, but the currency symbol never changes.

Can anything think of any reason this might be?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a template issue, make sure your template is using `formatPrice` method from core helper.

E.g.:

```
<?php $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core'); ?>
...
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
...
```

Start checking from `catalog/product/price.phtml`. Try also copying it from `base/default` to see if the issue is there.

Also try switching to default template to make a test and see if it fix (the problem can be somewhere else in your template).

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the reply. It seems to be using formatPrice everywhere, and even if I change it to the default template it still has the same problem. Can you think of anything else? I'm guessing it must be a config setting I have missed

Comment: The only setting I can guess is the currency symbol itself in the backend config. Did you double check it?